# Get all checked nodes of a treeview

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a treeview with many nodes and lots of children and descend nodes.
I would like to find the checked node by clicking on the treeview.
Then I wrote the following code:

```
internal static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNodeCollection tNode) 
{
    foreach (var node in tNode.OfType<TreeNode>())
    {
        yield return node;

        foreach (var child in node.Nodes.Descendants())
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}

var selectedNodes = treeView1.Nodes.Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.Checked)
                    .Select(n => n.Text)
                    .ToList();
```

But I have the following error:

> error CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

By the way I should mention that this error is for `public partial class Form1 : Form`.

Would you please let me know where is the problem?

Comment: It clearly mentions that your `Extension` method  must be in a `static` class

Comment: @Chaitanya Do you mean Form1: Form ?

Comment: I have to guess because you haven't specified in your question. Try to implement your `extension` method in a separate class. Maybe it can resolve your issue

Comment: @Chaitanya I have Updated my question and mentioned where is the error.

Comment: Add a new `Class` File and make that class `static` and add your `Extension` method. `public static class TreeViewHelper
{ publi static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNodeCollection tNode) 
{
   //your code
}`

Answer (score 0):

Write your extension method in a **SEPARATE** static class (not nested). Add another file to your project, and create a static class there, with your static extension method inside.

The error in your question (and the one you got from trying to add it to a nested class) should be self-explanatory